# Athena partitions data based on the location/date

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have the below config to read data from S3 written there by Kinesis Firehose:

```
S3AthenaStore:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName:  ${self:custom.s3AthenaStore}

AnalysisGlueDatabase:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Database
  Properties:
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    DatabaseInput:
      Name:  !Join 
        - ''
        - - '${self:custom.glueName}-'
          - 'db'
      Description: "Analysis aws Glue database"
  DependsOn:
    - S3AthenaStore

AnalyticsGlueRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  DependsOn:
    - S3AnalyticsStore
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        -
          Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            Service:
              - "glue.amazonaws.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
    Path: "/"
    ManagedPolicyArns:
      ['arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole']
    Policies:
      -
        PolicyName: "S3BucketAccessPolicy"
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: "Allow"
              Action: 
                - "s3:GetObject"
                - "s3:PutObject"
              Resource: 
                - !Join
                  - ''
                  - - !GetAtt S3AnalyticsStore.Arn
                    - "*"

AnalyticsGlueCrawler:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
  Properties:
    Name: "AnalysisCrawler"
    Role: !GetAtt AnalyticsGlueRole.Arn
    DatabaseName: !Ref AnalysisGlueDatabase
    Targets:
      S3Targets:
        - Path: !Ref S3AnalyticsStore
    SchemaChangePolicy:
      UpdateBehavior: "LOG"
      DeleteBehavior: "LOG"
    Schedule:
      ScheduleExpression: "cron(00 0/1 * * ? *)"
    RecrawlPolicy: 
      RecrawlBehavior: CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY
  DependsOn:
    - AnalyticsGlueRole
    - AnalysisGlueDatabase

AnalyticsAthenaWorkGroup:
  Type: AWS::Athena::WorkGroup
  Properties: 
    Name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-wg
    WorkGroupConfiguration: 
      ResultConfiguration:
        OutputLocation: 
          !Join
            - ''
            - - 's3://'
              - !Ref S3AthenaStore
  DependsOn:
    - S3AthenaStore
```

The data is the folders with the following pattern: `${bucket}/${year}/${month}/${date}/${hour}/event-collection-stream-staging-deliver-1-2022-07-14-23-51-22-cdb2f06a-e825-47d0-a781-efd4195ab88d.gz` and it looks like:

```
{"anonymous_id":"123","url":"-","event_type":"pageView","timestamp":"2022-07-12T03:29:47.186Z","source_ip":"69.113.177.222","user_agent":"curl/7.54.0"} {"anonymous_id":"123","url":"-","event_type":"pageView","timestamp":"2022-07-12T03:29:50.726Z","source_ip":"69.113.177.222","user_agent":"curl/7.54.0"} {"anonymous_id":"123","url":"-","event_type":"pageView","timestamp":"2022-07-12T03:29:53.628Z","source_ip":"69.113.177.222","user_agent":"curl/7.54.0"}
```

My question is - how come my data is automatically partitioned in Athena? When I run: `select * from page_view_store_staging`, it returns: my columns, plus columns for four (4) partitions 0-3 with column `partition_0` having a value of `2022` etc.

I did not specify this in my config, did I?

Comment: it could be kinesis firehose doing the partitioning for you

Comment: Its your crawler.  By default crawler tries to partition data.

Comment: thank you @Marcin should i leave the data partitioned, as it is now?

Comment: Its good practice to partition data. Can speed up queries a lot.

Comment: Partition allows you to speed up queries and reduce number of processed files(which leads to reducing the cost) if filtering applied based on partition columns.

Comment: If I am not utilizing those partitions for my queries, won't it just make the data set larger? I imagine that whenever a query would need to take into account time, it would utilize the timestamp value. understand how in general partitioning might be useful, but is it useful here, if we don't have use for those values?